# How to update cells in a spreadsheet without the values on the list repeating on openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm new to programming so sorry the silly question.

I have been trying to develop a spreadsheet on excel that updates the duties of staff members from a certain list.

For example I have this code:

```
senior_duties = ['SOPs', 'EQA review', 'Doc review', 'NC review', 'Trend analysis']

senior_duties1 = random.choice(senior_duties)

#Staff member 1

sheet["D5"] = senior_duties1
sheet["D6"] = senior_duties1

#Staff member 2

sheet["E5"] = senior_duties1
sheet["E6"] = senior_duties1
```

I understand that this only prints random values from the list that some times repeat and duplicate between two staff members.

I want the code to print something new for each staff member from the list every time the script is run. I'm sure the solution involves a 'for' loop but I just can't seem to solve it.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to randomly assign the duties to each staff member, just shuffle the list and assign the duties from the list.

```
import random

senior_duties = ['SOPs', 'EQA review', 'Doc review', 'NC review', 'Trend analysis']

random.shuffle(senior_duties)

# Staff member 1

sheet["D5"] = senior_duties[0]
sheet["D6"] = senior_duties[0]

# Staff member 2

sheet["E5"] = senior_duties[1]
sheet["E6"] = senior_duties[1]
```

This will give you a random duty assignment every time you run the script, however if you want an assignment that has not been done yet, you will need to add further logic

Answer (score 1):

To get a different outcome for each person, you'd need to call `random_choice` again:

```
senior_duties = ['SOPs', 'EQA review', 'Doc review', 'NC review', 'Trend analysis']

#Staff member 1
sheet["D5"] = random.choice(senior_duties)
sheet["D6"] = random.choice(senior_duties)

#Staff member 2
sheet["E5"] = random.choice(senior_duties)
sheet["E6"] = random.choice(senior_duties)
```

Or if it's the same choice for each staff member:

```
senior_duties = ['SOPs', 'EQA review', 'Doc review', 'NC review', 'Trend analysis']

#Staff member 1
duty_1 = random.choice(senior_duties)
sheet["D5"] = duty_1
sheet["D6"] = duty_1

#Staff member 2
duty_2 = random.choice(senior_duties)
sheet["E5"] = duty_2
sheet["E6"] = duty_2
```

Comment: This solution can still end up with staff members being assigned the same duties